# data comparision fails even though the value is same

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a code for a quiz test, here

```
            function run($id){
            //Is this the first question ?
            if($this->data){
                $question_no = $this->Session->read('Test.qno'); //0
                $last_answer = $this->Session->read('Test.last_answer');
                $question_no = $question_no + 1;                 //1
                $this->Session->write('Test.qno',$question_no);  //Test.qno = 1
                $this->Session->setFlash('last_answer'.$this->data['Test']['answer']);
                $this->redirect($this->referer());

                if($this->data['Test']['answer']==$last_answer){
                    $score = $this->Session->read('Test.score');
                    $score = $score + 1 ;
                    $this->Session->write('Test.score',$score);
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Correct answer');
                }
            }

            $question_no = $this->Session->read('Test.qno');    //question_no =
            if(!$question_no){
                $question_no = 0;
                $this->Session->write('Test.qno',$question_no);
                $this->Session->write('Test.score',0);
            }
            $question = $this->Test->Question->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Question.test_id ='=>$id),'offset'=>$question_no));
            $answer = $question['Question']['answer'];
            $this->Session->write('Test.last_answer',$answer);
            if(empty($question)){
                $score = $this->Session->read('Test.score');
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your Score is '.$score);
                $this->Session->write('Test.qno',0);
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'States','action'=>'index'));
                }
            else{
                $this->set(compact('question'));
                }
        }
```

here data comparison fails even though they both hold the same value can some one tell me why,here $last_answer is retrieved from session and holds a number.

$this->data['Test']['answer'] is taken from a form with radio button's

Comment: You should also post where and how `$last_answer` is being set.

Comment: Ross I have posted the complete code

Comment: Try [trimming](http://php.net/trim) both variables before comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
debug( '"'.$this->data['Test']['answer'].'"' );
debug( '"'.$last_answer.'"' );
```

to confirm they really are the same.

Also make sure it's not a problem with sessions (i.e. the condition is true, but the code inside doesn't do anything): add `debug( "true" );` inside the if block and confirm that you see the message.

**UPDATE** after seeing the whole code:

You have a `$this->redirect()` right before the if block! Of course the code you initially posted doesn't do anything because *you redirect the user to another page* before the execution even reaches it.

Comment: Why are you wrapping them in `'"'`?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: to confirm that there are no trailing spaces ("foo " vs "foo" ).

Comment: @juhana I don't see any message

Comment: @Pradeep The problem is the redirect before the if clause. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have put the redirect after the if and it is working fine, Thanks